# How can I access a member from another class with a Timer?

Tags: c#, pass-by-reference

I'm currently writing a class to calculate the average download speed over a defined period of time, taking a defined number of samples. The way I thought this would work is that this class runs a Timer object, which calls a method inside said class that will look at the bytes downloaded (maintained in a parent class, the FTPDownloadFile), and then store that sample in a Queue. My issue is accessing the number of bytes downloaded, however.

My method of accessing that information was through a reference that was passed in when the download calculating class was constructed, however, it seems like I'm not understanding/using references correctly. The variable that is passed in always appears to be 0, even though I can see the original variable changing.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong / suggest a better way for me to accomplish what I want to do?

First, here is the class that is handling the calculation of the download speed:

```
public class SpeedCalculator
    {
        private const int samples = 5;
        private const int sampleRate = 1000; //In milliseconds
        private int bytesDownloadedSinceLastQuery;
        private System.Threading.Timer queryTimer;
        private Queue<int> byteDeltas = new Queue<int>(samples);
        private int _bytesDownloaded;

        public SpeedCalculator(ref int bytesDownloaded)
        {
            _bytesDownloaded = bytesDownloaded;
        }

        public void StartPolling()
        {
            queryTimer = new System.Threading.Timer(this.QueryByteDelta, null, 0, sampleRate);
        }

        private void QueryByteDelta(object data)
        {
            if (byteDeltas.Count == samples)
            {
                byteDeltas.Dequeue();
            }

            byteDeltas.Enqueue(_bytesDownloaded - bytesDownloadedSinceLastQuery);
            bytesDownloadedSinceLastQuery = _bytesDownloaded;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Calculates the average download speed over a predefined sample size.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>The average speed in bytes per second.</returns>
        public float GetDownloadSpeed()
        {
            float speed;
            try
            {
                speed = (float)byteDeltas.Average() / ((float)sampleRate / 1000f);
            }
            catch {speed = 0f;}

            return speed;
        }
```

That class is contained inside of my FTPDownloadFile class:

```
class FTPDownloadFile : IDisposable
{
    private const int recvBufferSize = 2048;
    public int bytesDownloaded;
    public SpeedCalculator Speed;
    private FileStream localFileStream;
    FtpWebResponse ftpResponse;
    Stream ftpStream;
    FtpWebRequest ftpRequest;
    public List<string> log = new List<string>();
    private FileInfo destFile;

    public event EventHandler ConnectionEstablished;

    public FTPDownloadFile()
    {
        bytesDownloaded = 0;
        Speed = new SpeedCalculator(ref bytesDownloaded);
    }

    public void GetFile(string host, string remoteFile, string user, string pass, string localFile)
    {
        //Some code to start the download...
        Speed.StartPolling();
    }

    public class SpeedCalculator {...}
}
```

Comment: I've finihed adding examples, have fun:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common 'issue' with understanding 'ref' parameters in C#. You see, unlike C+, there are **no real value references** in C#.

In C++, when you pass-by-reference, you actually internally pass pointer to the variable. Therefore, you can have a class member variable of type "int&" that is actual reference to an integer stored elsewhere.

In C#, 'ref' or 'out' parameter works in a similar way, but noone talks about pointers. You *cannot* store the **reference**. You cannot have a 'ref' class member. Look at your class: the sotrage variable is of type 'int', plain 'int', not a reference.

You actually are passing that value by-ref, but then you copy it to the member variable. The 'reference' is gone at the point where your constructor ends.

To walk it around, you have to keep the actual source object, and either introduce a strong dependency, or a weak one by an interface, or do it lazy/functional way - by a delegate

Ex#1: strong reference

```
public class SpeedCalculator
{
    private const int samples = 5;
    private const int sampleRate = 1000; //In milliseconds
    private int bytesDownloadedSinceLastQuery;
    private System.Threading.Timer queryTimer;
    private Queue<int> byteDeltas = new Queue<int>(samples);

    private FTPDownloadFile downloader; // CHANGE

    public SpeedCalculator(FTPDownloadFile fileDownloader) // CHANGE
    {
        downloader = fileDownloader;
    }

    public void StartPolling()
    {
        queryTimer = new System.Threading.Timer(this.QueryByteDelta, null, 0, sampleRate);
    }

    private void QueryByteDelta(object data)
    {
        if (byteDeltas.Count == samples)
        {
            byteDeltas.Dequeue();
        }

        byteDeltas.Enqueue(_bytesDownloaded - bytesDownloadedSinceLastQuery);

        bytesDownloadedSinceLastQuery = downloader.bytesDownloaded; // CHANGE
    }

//and in the other file

public FTPDownloadFile()
{
    bytesDownloaded = 0;
    Speed = new SpeedCalculator( this ); // CHANGE
}
```

In C#, every object (`class MyObject`) is passed by reference, or implicit pointer, therefore taking FTPDownloadFile by parameter and assigning it to a member variable does not copy it, it is truly passed by ref (on the other hand, values (int, decimal, ..) and structs (`struct MyThing`) are always passed by value, so your original `_bytes = bytes` made a copy of int). Hence, later, I can just query the

Ex#2: "weak" reference

```
public interface IByteCountSource
{
    int BytesDownloaded {get;}
}

public class FTPDownloadFile : IDisposable, IByteCountSource
{
    .....
    public int BytesDownloaded { get { return bytesDownloaded; } }
    .....

    public FTPDownloadFile()
    {
       bytesDownloaded = 0;
       Speed = new SpeedCalculator( this ); // note no change versus Ex#1 !
    }
}

public class SpeedCalculator
{
    ....

    private IByteCountSource bts;

    public SpeedCalculator(IByteCountSource countSource) // no "FTP" information!
    {
        this.bts = countSource;
    }

    ...

    private void QueryByteDelta(object data)
    {
        ....

        bytesDownloadedSinceLastQuery = bts.BytesDownloaded;
    }
```

The first example was quick and dirty. In general, we usually want the classes to know as least as possible about all other. So why should the SpeedCalculator know about the FTPDownloadFile? All it needs to know is the current byte-count. So I introduced an interface to 'hide' the actual source behind. Now the SpeedCalculator can take the value from any object that implements the interface - be it FTPDownloadFile, HTTPDownloadFile or some DummyTestDownloader

Ex#3: delegates, anonymous functions, etc

```
public class SpeedCalculator
{
    ....

    private Func<int> bts;

    public SpeedCalculator(Func<int> countSource)
    {
        this.bts = countSource;
    }

    ...

    private void QueryByteDelta(object data)
    {
        ....

        bytesDownloadedSinceLastQuery = bts();
    }

// and in the other file

private int getbytes() { return bytesDownloaded; }

public FTPDownloadFile()
{
    bytesDownloaded = 0;
    Speed = new SpeedCalculator( this.getbytes ); // note it is NOT a getbytes() !
}

// or even

public FTPDownloadFile()
{
    bytesDownloaded = 0;
    Speed = new SpeedCalculator( () => this.bytesDownloaded ); // CHANGE
}
```

The example with an interface is pretty, but the interface was 'small'. One is ok, but sometimes you'd need to introduce dozens of such one-property or one-method interfaces, it gets somewhat boring and cluttering. Especially if all of that is 'internal implementation' that anyways isn't published for any other people to use. You can very easily drop such small interface with a short lambda, as in the third example. Instead of receiving and storing a object-that-implememts-an-interface, I changed the parameter to Func. This way I require to get "a method that returns an INT". Them, I pass the **some method**. Note that during `new SpeedCalculator`, I do not call the `this.getbytes()`, I pass the method without parenthesis - this causes the method to be wrapped into Func delegate, that will be later invoked as `bts()`, and will return current counter. This `getbytes` is rarely used, only in this one place - so I can even drop it completely and write anonymous function right at the point of constructor call, as you can see in the "or even" part.

However, I'd suggest you to stick with interfaces for now, they are much clearer to read and understand.

Comment: Wonderful. I never quite understood the purpose of interfaces, but I think I'm beginning to see the usefulness with your examples. I appreciate the fact that I didn't really have to store the whole FTP object in the other class as well. Thank you!

Comment: A parameter is by reference if there is `ref` or `out`, or by value otherwise. It does not matter what the type is.

Comment: "every object (class MyObject) is passed by reference" Objects are not values in C#, and therefore cannot be "passed". There are no "object types".

Comment: @quetzalcoatl: Yes, `X` in C# is equivalent to `X*` in C++ and `ref X` in C# is equivalent to `X*&` in C++. `&` is what determines whether you are passing by reference in C++, similar to how `ref` and `out` determines whether you are passing by reference in C#. So pass-by-reference and pass-by-value work the exact same way in C# and C++. I don't understand how you come to the conclusion that they don't. "Pass object by reference" in C++ means `X&`. It does not exist in C# because there are no object types like there are in C++. So that is why you cannot say "objects are passed" by anything.